# How can I make a tapable URL in Xamarin?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I used this code in Objetive-C:

```
static NSString *const kTableFooterHTMLFormatString = @"<html><head><style type='text/css'>body{font-family: '-apple-system','HelveticaNeue';font-size:14;text-align:center;color:#3a3a3a;-webkit-user-select:none;-webkit-touch-callout:none;}a{text-decoration:none;color:#0b51b0;}</style><meta charset='UTF-8'></head><body>Copyright ©%@ Company name. <br/> <a href='%@/privacy.do'>Privacy Policy</a> &amp; <a href='%@/termsOfUse.do'>Terms of Use</a></body></html>";

_tableFooterVC.htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:kTableFooterHTMLFormatString, [[NSDate date] yearString], currentBaseURLString, currentBaseURLString];
```

What would be the equivalent in Xamarin?

I found this on other Xamarin posts, but it loses the font, and formating:

```
var htmlLink = String.Format("<html><head><meta charset='UTF-8'></head><body>Copyright ©{0} Company name. <br /><a href='{1}/privacy.do'>Privacy Policy</a> &amp; <a href='{2}/termsOfUse.do'>Terms of Use</a></body></html>", "2016", "http://www.company.com", "http://www.company.com");

this.TermsLabel.AttributedText = new NSAttributedString(htmlLink, attr, ref nsError);
```

Part 2 of the question, I need the links tappable from UITESTS too. So, I would need id or someway of referencing the URLs for the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UILabel` do not support tappable links, so I am assuming the `TermsLabel` in your custom `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` is a selectable non-editable `UITextView`.

To set `AttributedText` that contains `html`:

```
var htmlString = @"<a href='http://xamarin.com/'>Xamarin</a>";
var error = new NSError();
var docAttributes = new NSAttributedStringDocumentAttributes()
{
    StringEncoding = NSStringEncoding.UTF8,
    DocumentType = NSDocumentType.HTML
};
(footer as CustomTableViewHeaderFooterView).TextView.AttributedText = new NSAttributedString(htmlString, docAttributes, ref error);
```

**Note:** The iOS HTML converter should only be used on the main/UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin,

You can use following peace of code.

```
NSAttributedStringDocumentAttributes attr = new NSAttributedStringDocumentAttributes();
            attr.DocumentType = NSDocumentType.HTML;
            NSError err = new NSError();
            NSAttributedString messageString = new NSAttributedString(NSData.FromString(model.TaskDescription), attr, ref err);
            ActivityDescription.AttributedText = messageString;
```

Here, Activity Description is my TextView